# unable to send java mail via SSL in Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, smtp, jakarta-mail

I am writing a simple java program to send mail to a particular Email ID using `java mail using SSL`

Following is my code

```
        public static String sendMail(String to)
        {
             String status_message = null;

             try 
             {
                   Properties props = new Properties();
                   props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
                   props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
                   props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                        "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
                   props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
                   props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

                   Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
                   new javax.mail.Authenticator() 
                   {
                       @Override
                       protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() 
                       {
                             return new PasswordAuthentication("sender@gmail.com","password");//change accordingly
                       }
                  });

               //compose message
                MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("sender@gmail.com"));//change accordingly
                message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));
                message.setSubject("Email Subject");
                message.setText("Text Content included in inside Email"); 

                //send message
                Transport.send(message);

                status_message = "success";
    } 
    catch (MessagingException ex) 
    {
                status_message = ex.getMessage();
    } 


}
```

When i ran this code inside a ***pariticular main Thread***. It worked ***successfully***.

But ***this same didn't worked*** when i included it `inside a function called within a servlet`

When i read the status_message value. It's showing `smtp`.

Can anyone help me find out what the issue is. Am i missing anything ?
I want to send mail through a jsp servlet.

Comment: Posting useless statements like "didn't work" is basically a waste of time. Post the exception, stack trace, etc.

Comment: @EJP status_message contains the error message and it displays smtp...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made several of the [common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).  Correct them and see if that solves your problem.